# You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1. How do I change the version?

Tags: android, css, google-play, google-play-services

I am trying to upload my apk on google play . The apk file is unity3d . Google play wont let me be I already have the version . I get this message on google play.You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1. I have rebuild the project and change the version to 2. I have also made changes in the android manifest script and I still couldn't upload the apk file. Here are the scripts that I had made changes so I can upload on google play :

{

```css
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.7" package="com.Be.Jackson" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <!-- Required for Nearby Connections API -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.SERVICE_ID" android:value="" />
    <!-- the space in these forces it to be interpreted as a string vs. int -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="\ 643756129390" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion" android:value="\ 0.9.34" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

}

{

```css
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.Be.Jackson" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionName="2.0" android:versionCode="2">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
</manifest>
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Just change the versionCode in your manifest. Your current versionCode is 2, change it to 3.

Replace

`android:versionCode="2"`

with

`android:versionCode="3"`

Each time you upload a new version, increment your versionCode by 1.

You should also try modifying your versionCode and versionName in build.gradle.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.you.yourpackage"
    minSdkVersion XX
    targetSdkVersion XX
    versionCode 3      // new versionCode
    versionName "1.7"  // new versionName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your version code is..add it by 1.

```
android:versionCode="X + 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its in your gradle file, and gets written to your manifest (if you aren't using gradle).